# fail using hash_map<vector<int>,string>, why?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I have implemented this code, but fail at compilation (VC2008 Express Ed.) :
Now all code is here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <hash_map>

using namespace std;
using namespace stdext;

typedef vector type_key;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    type_key key;

    hash_map<type_key, string> map_segment;
    hash_map<type_key, string>::iterator iter_map_segment;

    iter_map_segment = map_segment.find(key);

    return 0;
}
```

using unordered_map also occurs the same error too.

but replacing the container by a map error does not occur.
What can be done to correct?
Thank you.

[EDITED]
Error info :

```
------ Build started: Project: map_key_test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Compiling...
map_key_test.cpp
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xhash(75) : error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const type_key' to 'size_t'
        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xhash(128) : see reference to function template instantiation 'size_t stdext::hash_value<_Kty>(const _Kty &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Kty=type_key
        ]
        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xhash(127) : while compiling class template member function 'size_t stdext::hash_compare<_Kty,_Pr>::operator ()(const _Kty &) const'
        with
        [
            _Kty=type_key,
            _Pr=std::less<type_key>
        ]
        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\hash_map(78) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stdext::hash_compare<_Kty,_Pr>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Kty=type_key,
            _Pr=std::less<type_key>
        ]
        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xhash(191) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stdext::_Hmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Tr,_Alloc,_Mfl>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Kty=type_key,
            _Ty=std::string,
            _Tr=stdext::hash_compare<type_key,std::less<type_key>>,
            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const type_key,std::string>>,
            _Mfl=false
        ]
        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\hash_map(88) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stdext::_Hash<_Traits>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Traits=stdext::_Hmap_traits<type_key,std::string,stdext::hash_compare<type_key,std::less<type_key>>,std::allocator<std::pair<const type_key,std::string>>,false>
        ]
        c:\users\salamon\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\map_key_test\map_key_test.cpp(17) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stdext::hash_map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Kty=type_key,
            _Ty=std::string
        ]
Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\Salamon\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\map_key_test\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
map_key_test - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

[EDITED]
Complete solution :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <hash_map>
using namespace std;
using namespace stdext;

class Vector : public vector<int>
{
public:
    operator size_t() const { return (*this).size(); };
};
typedef Vector type_key;

struct less_vector
{
    bool operator()(const Vector & x, const Vector & y) const
    {
        if ( x != y )
            return true;

        return false;
    }
};

struct greater_vector
{
    bool operator()(const Vector & x, const Vector & y) const
    {
        if ( x == y )
            return true;

        return false;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Vector key;
    string str;

    hash_map<Vector, string, hash_compare <Vector, less_vector > > map_segment;
    hash_map<Vector, string, hash_compare <Vector, greater_vector > >::iterator iter_map_segment;

    //
    key.push_back(0);
    key.push_back(1);
    key.push_back(2);
    str = "012";
    map_segment [key] = str;
    //
    key.clear();
    key.push_back(1);
    key.push_back(0);
    key.push_back(2);
    str = "102";
    map_segment [key] = str;
    //
    key.clear();
    key.push_back(2);
    key.push_back(1);
    key.push_back(0);
    str = "210";
    map_segment [key] = str;
    //
    key.clear();
    key.push_back(1);
    key.push_back(0);
    key.push_back(2);

    iter_map_segment = map_segment.find(key);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the text of the error the compiler gives you. The compiler errors give a lot of information that helps to debug the problem. Plus, it will be more helpful for people in the future who have the same error and are searching for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure that the header  that you include really exists on your installation.

Second, hash_map is in the `stdext` namespace, make sure you make this name visible via specifying it explicitly as `stdext::hash_map`, or via a `using` directive.

Third, where are the template arguments for your hash_map in your code? I only see `hash_map` and not `hash_map<vector<int>,string>`.

Fourth, I'm not sure if std::vector can be used as a hash key for a hash map just like this. You need to define a hash function for your key (via implementing a `hash_compare` function object and passing it to the `hash_map` as third template parameter). Anyway storing these vectors by value is hardly a good idea, instead you should probably consider using pointers to these vectors as keys.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it works, I smell fish... Under what circumstance do you want to use a vector-of-ints as a key to retrieve a string attribute from a hash-map?

Sounds like poor/no design to me... just think about the expense of calculating all those hashCodes for a start.

Comment: Definitely agree that looking up a string based on a vector of ints seems fishy.  Maybe it's meant to be the other way around?

Comment: It may seem strange but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

To compare the keys, <,==,> operators should be defined. The find() function here doesn't know how to compare the keys.